# How to search records using a date

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am using a `datagridview` to show student records..

I want to display records filtered by the date of birth of the hosteler.

When I search the data by selecting 11/09 from a `datetimepicker` using the custom format `dd/mm` and it is showing nothing.

How can I display all records by matching only dd/mm while ignoring the year?

Here is my code:

```
Try
    con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
    con.Open()

    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT HostelerID as [Hosteler ID],HostelerName as [Hosteler Name],DOB,HostelName as [Hostel Name],RoomNo as [Room No],DateOfJoining as [Date Of Joining],Purpose,FatherName as [Father's Name],MobNo1 as [Mobile No],Phone1 as [Phone No],MotherName as [Mother's Name],MobNo2 as [Mobile No 2],City,Address,Email,ContactNo as [Contact No],InstOfcDetails as [Ins/Ofc Details],Phone2 as [Phone No 2],Agreement,GuardianName as  [Guardian Name],GuardianAddress as [Guardian Address],MobNo3 as [Guardian Mobile No],Phone3 as [Guardian Phone No],FixedDeposit as [Fixed Deposit],CompletionDate as [Completion Date],Photo,DocsPic as [Docs Pic] from Hostelers where DOB like #" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "# order by HostelerName", con)

    Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()

    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Hostelers")

    DataGridView6.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("Hostelers").DefaultView

    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

Comment: is it possible to fetch data using regular expression in MS access ?

Comment: please someone help :(

Comment: It takes more than 60 seconds for people to see this.  I just edited the question to make it easier for folks to even understand what you are trying to do.  Be patient.  Meaning, come back in an hour or so.

Comment: Putting a date string between # is not the way to express date in NET. You should use a parameter of type Date

Comment: bro. i am using MS Access not sql server....it is giving me correct record when i am selecting exact entered dob from datetimepicker...but i want search using dd/mm ignoring year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the 'where' clause to:

```
" WHERE MONTH(DOB) = " & DateTimePicker1.Value.Month &
      " AND DAY(DOB) = " & DateTimePicker1.Value.Day
```

However I would also strongly recommend you using parameterized SQL commands 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx

This will prevent SQL injection (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=SQL.105).aspx) and other errors

Comment: it worked for me...thanks a ton bro. and thanks stackoverflow.com to help beginner like me :)

Answer (score 2):

*"search the data by selecting 11/09 from a datetimepicker using the custom format dd/mm"*

In the Access query, you can ask the db engine to apply `Format()` to your `DOB` value and then do the comparison.  This would do it for the static value *'11/09'* ...

```sql
WHERE Format(DOB, 'dd/mm') = '11/09'
```

To make it flexible, you can use a parameter query and supply `DateTimePicker1.Text` as the parameter value.

```sql
WHERE Format(DOB, 'dd/mm') = your_string
```

Comment: Didn't know this.  Interesting;

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to something like this:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("
SELECT HostelerID as [Hosteler ID], HostelerName as [Hosteler Name], 
    DOB, HostelName as [Hostel Name],
    RoomNo as [Room No], DateOfJoining as [Date Of Joining], 
    Purpose, FatherName as [Father's Name],
    MobNo1 as [Mobile No], Phone1 as [Phone No], 
    MotherName as [Mother's Name], MobNo2 as [Mobile No 2],
    City, Address, Email, ContactNo as [Contact No], 
    InstOfcDetails as [Ins/Ofc Details], Phone2 as [Phone No 2],
    Agreement, GuardianName as  [Guardian Name],
    GuardianAddress as [Guardian Address], MobNo3 as [Guardian Mobile No],
    Phone3 as [Guardian Phone No], FixedDeposit as [Fixed Deposit],
    CompletionDate as [Completion Date], Photo, DocsPic as [Docs Pic] 
FROM Hostelers 
WHERE (DatePart(\"M\", DOB) = '" + DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.Month + '")
  AND (DatePart(\"D\", DOB) = '" + DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.Day + '"))
ORDER BY HostelerName
")
```